# Make critical section from part of pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have few working nodes which can work simultaneously except few commands in pipeline script.
How I can make something like critical section in jenkins pipeline to only single node can perform these operations while others agents are waiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `lock` step from the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin), as described in this [blog post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need.